# Using the following code, I am getting error because it doesn't recoginze 'dfg'? create_price_ratio(dfg[dfg['London_Borough']=='Barking & Dagenham'])

Tags: python, dataframe

I am writing the following code using dfg but it is throwing an error.

```
def create_price_ratio(d):
    y1998 = float(d['Average_price'][d['Year'] == 1998])
    y2018 = float(d['Average_price'][d['Year'] == 2018])
    ratio = y2018 / y1998
    return ratio


 create_price_ratio(dfg[dfg['London_Borough']=='Barking & Dagenham'])
```

I tried replacing 'dfg with 'df' and tried to define dfg in previous code which it did not work. I think my issue is that 'dfg' is not in my dataset perhaps?

Comment: What is `dfg`? Please [edit] to post a sample of `dfg`.